# How to implement these remarks in my Redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I created an application on Redux.
 But the person who checked my application made a remarks about this code:

**file index.js(action):**

```
export function fetchData(day) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", day });
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);
    const data = (await response.json()).body;
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: { data, day } });
  };
}
export function setShift(shift) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_SHIFT", shift });
  };
}
```

such remarks:

> 1) in the index.js file should not have a dispatch method. Dispatch
>   method must be located in function matchDispatchToProps in file
>   app.js(container)

---

**file app.js(container):**

```
export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

const days = ["12-11-2019", "13-11-2019", "14-11-2019"];

class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(days[this.props.propsReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.props.propsReducer;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content">

        <Header/>
        <br/>
        <div className="searchTitle">SEARCH FLIGHT</div>
             <br/>
        <TableSearch value={search} onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
         onSearch={value => onFilter({ search: value })}/>
             <br/>
             <br/>
        <div className="buttonShift">
          {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
            <button data-shift={n} onClick={e => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })} className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}>
                {n}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="row">
        <span className="title">Yesterday: </span><span className="title">Today: </span><span className="title">Tomorrow: </span>
        </div>

        <div className="buttonDays">
          {days && days.map((day, i) => (
            <button  key={day} onClick={() => onFetchData(day)} className="buttonDaysOne">
                {day} 
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} />}
          </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  state => state,
  dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args }),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch({ type: "SET_SEARCH", search }),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

> 1) in file app.js(containers) should not be actions: `{ type:
>   "RUN_FILTER", ...args }` `{ type: "SET_SEARCH", search }` This
>   actions must be located in file index.js(actions)

> 2) This function should not look like this:

```
export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  state => state,
  dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args }),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch({ type: "SET_SEARCH", search }),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

It must be something like this:

[image]

That is, there must be methods: `matchDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps`. And then this methods need to write in method connect.
Please help to implement this. I just started to study the reducer and unfortunately I cannot implement it in not to break the app...

Code in sandbox(ignore the sandbox error when I running the program in a text editor this error is gone and the application is work well):

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-ho1j4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-2mrdu)

Move *all* your actions into `src/actions/index.js`:

```js
// src/actions/index.js

// ...other content

export function setSearch(search) {
  return dispatch => dispatch({ type: "SET_SEARCH", search });
}

export function runFilter(args) {
  return dispatch => dispatch({ type: "RUN_FILTER", ...args });
}
```

Then, in `src/containers/app.js`:

```
import { setSearch, runFilter, fetchData } from "../actions";

// ...

const mapStateToProps = state => state;

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onFilter: args => runFilter(...args),
  onSetSearch: search => setSearch(search),
  onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
});

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Root);
```

## Explanation

### First critique

They just want you to keep *all* your actions in a single location. This is common practice for larger scale applications.

So you'd define action creators in `src/actions/index.js` that do exactly what you're doing already.

### Second critique

They want you to define specific functions called `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and reference them when you invoke `connect()`.

Again, this doesn't change the behaviour of your application, this is just a common pattern.

Comment: thank you very much! but now the departure and arrival buttons do not work. Report an error. The search filter does not work either. Can't find airplane by flight number. It is not even possible to enter the input into the input. You can see how this should work in my slightly older version of the sandbox (where the default state description was not in the reducer and in the createStore(not architecturally correct) but at the time the application was still working) Here is a previous version of the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-i55md